# Django Channels Web Socket Connection Keeps Closing

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I created the following consumers in my django application to handle real time notifications:

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = f"notification_{self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['user_id']}"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()
        
# other methods below
```

and i have my routing to this consumer here:

```
from django.urls import re_path, path
from .consumers import NotificationConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('notification/<int:user_id>/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Then i am connecting to this in the frontend with javascript:

```
const websocketProtocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
const wsEndpoint = `${websocketProtocol}://${window.location.host}/notification/{{request.user.id}}/`;
          const socket = new WebSocket(wsEndpoint);

socket.onopen = (event) => {
    console.log("WebSocket connection opened!");
};

socket.onclose = (event) => {
     console.log("WebSocket connection closed!");
};
```

It works locally on my computer but when i hosted it on a live domain, each time i load the page where this web socket was created, i get the following error in the console:

`tutor-message-list/:236 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.youvarsity.org/notification/2/' failed:`

and then the close event fires off and logs to the console:

`WebSocket connection closed!`

It worked locally and i have tried debugging but i do not know how to solve this. Please help